# Reversing a queue using recursion and returning a new queue

Tags: c, recursion, queue, reverse

I have to create a function that receives a single parameter, this being the queue, and returns a new queue created within the function and I don't really know how to do it and what I'm doing wrong.

```
Queue * reverse(Queue * f) {
    Queue * n = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    n = create_queue();
    if (empty_queue(f)) {
        return n;
    }else {
        int v = pop_queue(f);
        f = reverse(f);
        push_queue(n, v);
    }
}
```

In case of doubt, my queue is like that:

```
typedef struct queue Queue;
typedef struct elemqueue ElemQueue;
struct elemfila {
    int info;
    ElemQueue* next;
};
struct fila {
    ElemQueue * start;
    ElemQueue * end;
};
```

I'm calling it like that:

```
int main(void) {
    Queue * f;
    f = create_queue();
    push_queue(f, 2);
    push_queue(f, 4);
    push_queue(f, 6);

    f = reverse(f);

    while (!empty_queue(f)) {
        int n = pop_queue(f);
        printf(" %d ", n);
    }

    free_queue(f);
    return 0;
}
```

As it shows, my queue is [2|4|6] (just an example) and I want it to turn to [6|4|2] and print it.

Comment: This is a nice start, but please edit to show your calling code, and if any input, include that, and explicitly say what your expected output, or behavior is. This would bring it close, it not all the way to being a [mcve].

Comment: That's what I've just done, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new queue. If the queue is empty, return the queue that was given.

When you are re-pushing the elements after the recursive call, you should logically push into the queue that was returned.

If your queue is not empty, your function fails to return anything.

If I were rewriting the body of your function, it would look like:

```
    if (!empty_queue(f)) {
        int v = pop_queue(f);
        push_queue(reverse(f), v);
    }
    return f;
```

If you insist that a new queue be created, I would do it when an empty queue is detected.

```
    if (empty_queue(f)) {
        return create_queue();
    }
    int v = pop_queue(f);
    f = reverse(f);
    push_queue(f, v);
    return f;
```

In this implementation, it is assumed the caller owns the queue that was passed in, and is in charge of destroying the old queue that is now empty.